# Which event gets dispatched when Update Cart action is triggered in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, cart, event-observer

I am trying to modify the subtotal in the checkout/cart page when the item gets updated using the **Update Cart action button on the product page**. After the product has been successfully added to the cart for the very first time, I tried to intercept the below events when I click on the **Edit button from the checkout/cart page** then I click on **Update Cart button from product page**. I really want to learn this concept it would be really helpful for me if someone can guide me. Though I will try my best to solve and update here.

```
checkout_cart_update_items_before
checkout_cart_update_items_after
checkout_cart_product_update_after
```

`checkout_cart_update_items_before` and `checkout_cart_update_items_after` does not get called at all not sure why no errors or warnings. Well, I was able to intercept checkout_cart_product_update_after where I added my custom code and results in me the highlighted part in the image. Now I am trying to update the subtotal by adding that digitization fee to it. So the subtotal should show around $30 on the checkout/cart page after the subtotal has been updated. Also, this is a configurable product that I am working with

*\app\code\Noname\Checkout\etc\events.xml*

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_update_after">
        <observer name="noname_cart_product_update_after" instance="Noname\Checkout\Observer\CartUpdateProductAfter" />
    </event>
```

*\app\code\Noname\Checkout\Observer\CartUpdateProductAfter.php*

```
<?php
namespace Noname\Checkout\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CartUpdateProductAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /** @var \Noname\Core\Helper\CustomerHelper$customerSession */
        $customerSession = $objectManager->create("\Noname\Core\Helper\CustomerHelper");


        //THIS BELOW CODE ADD A CUSTOM EXTRA OPTION TO THE ITEM

        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $additionalOptions = array();
        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')){
            $additionalOptions = (array) unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
        }
        $infoBuyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest()->getData();
        $digitizationfee = $infoBuyRequest['digitizationfee'];
        $additionalOptions[] = [
            'label' => 'Digitization Fee',
            'value' => $digitizationfee
        ];

        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
            $item->addOption(array(
                'product_id' => $item->getProductId(),
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));

            $customerSession->getSessionManager()->setData("last_updated_item",$item->getQuoteId());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: This related to totals, I think you should use CollectTotal for this task

Comment: How to get last added quote item id in the observer from getQuoteItem()? what I tried is         
`$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$quote=$item->getQuote();
foreach($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $i){
       var_dump($i->getId());
}` but it is giving NULL for itemid